# is it possible to update particular value of json using powershell script?

Tags: azure, powershell, key-value, secret-key

```
az keyvault secret set --vault-name "" --name "AppSecret" --description "An optional description" --disabled false --value "{`"type`":`"XXXXXX`",`"project_id`":`"XXXXXX`",`"private_key_id`":`"XXXXXXXX`"}"
```

I have created above secret , is it possible to update particular value of secret using powershell ?

Comment: I believe it's readonly. An update will generate a new version of the secret

Comment: how can i set value for particular attribute ? I am not getting . Can you please help me? @Thiago Custodio

Comment: What do you mean the particular value?

Comment: @CharlesXu I mean to say there may be multiple keys in that json secret , so wht if i have to update only single key,

Comment: Why not get the key which you want to change and update it directly?

Comment: @CharlesXu yes i did it.

Answer (score 0):

[Yes you can set a keyvault secret via Powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.keyvault/Set-AzKeyVaultSecret?view=azps-3.8.0).  It will create a new version; however, applications will either automatically get the new version or if referencing a specific version continue to get the same value associated with that version.

```
$Secret = ConvertTo-SecureString -String 'Password' -AsPlainText -Force    
Set-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName 'Contoso' -Name 'ITSecret' -SecretValue $Secret
```

Comment: Thank you for you reply

Comment: how can i set value for particular attribute ? I am not getting . Can you please help me? @DreadedFrost

Comment: @sau secrets are KEY Value pairs, you can't just access / replace one attribute, but the entire value content

Comment: @DreadedFrost  yes , i unserstood but there must be some code to get or set particular value . e.g by applying pipe or something like that

Comment: The snippet above shows that. The first line creates a secure string and the second line sets the value for a secret named "ITSecret" to the value of the secure string.

Answer (score -1):

I have developed one simple solution :

If i have json secret like :

{
  "Key1" : "123"
  "Key2" : "456"
}

and i want to update only key1 then :

1 ) `$secret = Get-AzureKeyVaultSecret -vaultname xyz -name abc`

2 ) `$secretValue = $secret.SecretValueText`

3 ) `$OldValue = "123"`

```
  $NewValue = "456
```

"

4 ) `$secretValue -match $OldValue`

```
$newJson = $secretValue -replace $OldValue,$NewValue
```

5 )

```
az keyvault secret set --vault-name "SaurabhD-Test" --name "cvljson" --disabled false 
    --value $newJson
```